# python ssh netmiko pathos client server, processing files paths from server vs. client GIS

Tags: multiprocessing, client-server, gis, pathos, netmiko

So I'm on a win workstation running a python script for GIS processing for very large .tif files. There is a linux server that I want to use the processing power from. I've ssh'ed into the server (netmiko) and set up pathos multiprocessing to run on the node. Works great on small projects. When I scaled it up, it was crashing due to memory allocation on workstation.

I realized the the workstation was trying to load everything into memory.

I have mapped the working tif file directory in the in the ubuntu server.

how do I call and store the file paths relative to the server in python, bypassing the workstation file directories, and call the objects relative to the worker node?

Currently looking into celery with RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

Well, I talked to my networking guys and they built me a cluster to directly code from, woot woot. I think gRPC could have handled this too.